# Integrating MVC3 App using IWA with OKTA

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, okta

This is my first web application, i am using IWA to authenticate. My Sysadmin wants me to allow OKTA (SSO implementation) to push users creds to the site and not prompt for login. I am a bit out of my realm here...does anyone know if this is possible? i have not found and resources addressing this on OKTA's site.

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach is to federate authentication of your application (ie. saml-enabling) your app to avoid the "pushing" of creds completely.

What your sysadmin is referring to as "push user creds" is the ability to "post" creds on the login page of your app to simulate login.  While Okta does support this feature, from an application standpoint, you still need to handle credentials for each user.  By SAML-enabling your app, you eliminate the need for credentials all together.  Okta can SSO into your application via a SAML response.  For further guidance on SAML - you can visit our page here (http://developer.okta.com/docs/getting_started/saml_guidance.html).

Hope this helps - and feel free to ask more questions as you are working your way through.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at that link, and look forward to questions as i start to dive in. :-) I am vaguely familiar with the idea of SAML and what it does, never played with it in development so it will be quite a learning experience for me. Thanks again.